# PHP/Javascript iFrame redirect SSL error

Tags: php, javascript, http

I have a problem with a redirect I am trying to do from within a iframe, I keep getting a SSL certificate error, is there a specific way  should be redirecting from within an iframe? I am usig this code,

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$redirect';</script>";
```

I have also tried a standard PHP header redirect, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: what is the certificate error that you are receiving? Mixed content warning, certificate expired, certificate doesn't match site? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively try

```
window.open('$redirect','_top');
```

It looks like you are going to break the back button too.
I would do

```
top.location.replace('$redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is the url in `$redirect`? Does the url match the exact certificate?

Comment: It's a facebook redirect, and the URL is being generated by the getLoginUrl() method.